# McAfee for Linux

Tags: linux, anti-virus

I have a set of 20 Windows PC's running in VLAN and I'm planning to implement McAfee On-Demand scan. I will update .DAT and run Full scan on each PC.

I also have one PC running Linux. I'm planning to use it for On-Access scan because we often use USB flash drives.

The plan is: before using flash drive on any of 20 PC's it should be scanned on that dedicated Linux machine. I plan to update .DAT on Linux the same way I will do on Windows.

My questions:

1. Is McAfee VirusScan free and I could download rpm or I should buy it?
2. Could I use the same .DAT file for both Windows and Linux?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am debating if I could use Linux OS for On-Access scan and in case it'll be more problem I'll try to find one more Windows PC

Comment: It doesn't appear to run on Linux. See http://www.mcafee.com/us/products/virusscan-enterprise.aspx#vtab-SystemRequirements=&vt=vtab-SystemRequirements

Comment: Well ...  based on this link it works on Linux as well: http://www.mcafee.com/us/products/virusscan-enterprise-for-linux.aspx#vt=vtab-SystemRequirements